# Chrome - certificate settings in Registry

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, registry

For a Webdrivertest I'm using Chrome, but there is always a query for one SSL-certificate. With Google Chrome setting its not possible to handle it. So I read that there is a way about Registry.
So I tried various combinations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / Software /Policies / Chrome / AutoSelectCertificateForUrls 
name = 1   
Value = {\"pattern\":\"url\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"User cert\"}}}
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / Software /Policies / Google / Chrome / AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
name = 1   
Value = {"pattern":"url","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"User cert}}}
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / Software /Policies / Chromium / AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
name = 1    
Value = {"pattern":"url","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"User cert"}}}
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / Software /Policies / Google Chrome / AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
name = 1   
Value = {\"pattern\":\"url\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"User cert\"}}}
```

and other combinations. 
When I go to chrome://policy I found it.

So it is in the policy, but it does not work. I still got the query for certificate.
Any one an idea why it does not work?

Comment: For Value, what is URL? The URL/domain of the site for which we're trying to authenticate, or domain of whomever is issuing the cert? Or the serial number of the certificate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first option works for me. I've saved the text below as a windows registry file (.reg). After importing it, chrome works as expected.

Notice that you don't need to escape the parenthesis if you are editing the registry directly using regedit.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"https://example.com\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"IssuerCN\"}}}"
```

(replace *https://example.com* and *IssuerCN* with your values, of course)

For further help, see https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls

Comment: Maybe it helps someone: In my cenario i changed ISSUER to SUBJECT since I wanted the subject's CN.