# Selenium/Protractor & Chrome - Client certificate

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

When trying to access a specific test environment with Chrome, spawned by protractor/ selenium webdriver, a chrome popup is displayed prompting me to select the client certificate to use to authenticate with this site.
There's only one certificate installed - is there any way for this to be autoselected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome - certificate settings in Registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510054/chrome-certificate-settings-in-registry)

Comment: @BigAl the answer you mention is windows-specific

Comment: @AlexandrosD did you ever find an answer to this then?

Comment: @Willwsharp not one that was viable.. ended up using a proxy/address that did not require client certificate

Comment: @AlexandrosD Ah I see, thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following configuration to `Protractor` `conf.js`:

```
capabilities : {
    browserName : 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {args: ['--test-type']}
    }
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference, unfortunately.